# Send message to Facebook contact when they're using mobile

Tags: facebook

If next to someone's name in a Facebook chat room you see "6h" with something that looks like mobile phone beside it, the person is most likely using mobile Facebook.

How then do you  get in touch with them about something important?

Answer (score -1):

If the person has activated email and mobile notification feature.. you can send message to that person in fb and if it is not seen within 5-10 min they will get an email saying "your name " has sent a message to you..... and also an text message will be sent...